# How set scrolling only for BorderLayout.CENTER?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-layouts, lwuit-list

I have top bar, list and bottom bar.

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, bottomBar);
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, list);
this.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottomBar);
```

`List` is very long. bottomBar and bottomBar is hide. Scrolling  is on the full screen. 
How to make that scrolling was only for `BorderLayout.CENTER`. bottomBar and bottomBar will be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the scrollable in the `Form`. For example do like this,

```
Form f = new Form();
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.setScrollable(false);
f.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Label("Top bar"));
f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, list);
f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("Bottom bar"));
f.show();
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, then please mark it as accepted to help the future readers.